# Using multiple wire/rings to provide more current in Slip Ring connector

Tags: current, resistance, slip-ring

I'm going to use a slip ring connector ([such as this one](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1196)) to power 6 servos on the other end of a rotary. This slip ring is rated for 2A of current per wire/ring.

If the 6 servos share a common +6v and ground, they will easily exceed 2A current draw. My naive understanding of conductance tells me that if I use two of the wires for +6v instead of one (and two for ground), I can effectively double the amount of current available to the servos because the first wire/ring (the one with initial least resistance) will heat up as it approaches the maximum rated current, becoming more resistant than the alternate wire/ring.

Am I wrong to assume that this setup would allow me to provide more than 2A through the slip ring?

Comment: I read the specifications sheet as 2 amps per ring, not per wire.

Comment: @Marla I think one wire is connected to one ring.

Comment: I stand corrected. I just looked further, to page 23 of spec sheet, where it shows number of rings and number of wires.  Spot on @EugeneSh.

Comment: Anyway, you can do it and your understanding is right. But bear in mind it will produce a ground loop and also if one ring is breaking, the other one will likely burn as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're looking at 6 servos, with one control line per servo, I'd recommend splitting up your servos into pairs, each pair using one power and one ground line. This will total 12 wires, a perfect match for your connector.

Comment: I appreciate the recommendation, but the hope is to use the other wires for an IMU - this is why I am trying to share all the +/- connections from servos to the power source.

Comment: @BlakeRegalia - Keep in mind that if you double up on the +6 line, you'll need to double up also on the ground wires, which only leaves 2 spare wires.

Comment: Rethinking your suggestion, I do realize now why it would make more sense to cluster servo power onto the separate lines. Instead of doing pairs, I can connect two groups of three servos to each +/-, using 4 wires for power, 6 wires for control, and sparing 2 for the IMU.